# Security Measures for HTML Anchor Download Feature

Tags: html

Do I need to explore security measures for the native HTML `<a download>` feature? What are some ways that this feature opens my website up to potential threats, and how should I mitigate those threats? Or (fingers crossed) have I nothing to worry about here?

Comment: This question is missing essential context: who provides this tag and its attributes and who provides the file to download. If any of this is provided by a potentiell attacker then misuse might be possible, for example by giving a different file name in the HTML tag than the actual file name served and thus bypassing some content inspection.

Comment: The file is static on the server, and the attribute is coded in to the page by us. I'm wondering (maybe unnecessarily) if the action of downloading the file, thus opening a link from the server to the user's machine, is cause for any proactive security measures, or is it not possible to backwards engineer this function in any way.

Comment: Such downloads can happen even without the `download` attribute, i.e. every content type which can not be handled inline by the browser is downloaded. What type of file is it, what `Content-Type` is used to deliver the file and what file name is set either in the `download` attribute or in the `Content-Disposition` header (if any file name is set at all)?

Comment: *thus opening a link from the server to the user's machine*. This is done when the user connects to the webserver to get the web page. You should of course keep a public facing service up to date, but there's no difference between getting a webpage and getting a file to store on disk. Both behave exactly the same from the servers viewpoint!

Comment: in short: there's nothing  extra to worry about.